# Shell navigation doesn't update view

Tags: xaml, xamarin, .net-maui

I have a Shell MAUI app with two pages: a form and a list. After inserting a new record with the form and navigating to the list page, it's not updated. I can easily achieve this without MVVM using this:

```
 private void OnBackToMenu(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
    }
```

How can I achieve the same with MVVM?

Here's my shell:

```
<Shell
    x:Class="Production.Savings.Maui.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Production.Savings.Maui"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Production.Savings.Maui.Views"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

    <TabBar>
        <Tab Title="Transactions">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:TransactionsPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Add New">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:AddNewPage}" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>

</Shell>


public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(TransactionsPage), typeof(TransactionsPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(AddNewPage), typeof(AddNewPage));
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Production.Savings.Maui.Views.TransactionsPage"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Production.Savings.Maui.ViewModels"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Production.Savings.Maui.Models"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:TransactionsViewModel"
             Title="TransactionsPage">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <CollectionView x:Name="transactionsList"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Transactions}"
                        SelectionMode="None">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Transaction">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Amount}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>

public partial class TransactionsPage : ContentPage
{
    public TransactionsPage(TransactionsViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = vm;
    } 
}
```

Viewmodel:

```
public partial class TransactionsViewModel: ObservableObject
{
    public TransactionsViewModel()
    {
        Transactions = new ObservableCollection<Transaction>(App.TransactionRepository.GetAllTransactions());
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    ObservableCollection<Transaction> transactions;
}
```

Comment: `After inserting a new record with the form and navigating to the list page, it's not updated `  Sorry, I don't quite understand you by words ` it's not updated`. Could you please explain it in detail?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT the list isn't updated. I put a breakpoint in the constructor and it doesn't get called, so the property doesn't fetch the data from the database.

Comment: *"After inserting a new record with the form and navigating to the list page,"* - which part of the code does this? Also, did you have one or more records showing, and then you added another one? Or is this the FIRST record?

Comment: `After inserting a new record with the form and navigating to the list page, it's not updated`  Where did you insert a new record? Could you please post a basic demo so that we can help you better?